# Backbone.js - sharing part of a model with another view

Tags: backbone.js

I have a parent view with parent model, and a child view.

I would like to pass a reference to *part of the model* (a collection) to the child model, so the child model can monitor this for changes and react accordingly.

I'm not sure about the best way to do this - possibly one of these approaches?

- **Pass whole model** : I don't want to do this, as the model contains a
  bunch of stuff that the child shouldn't know about.
- **Pass part of the model** : I don't think this is possible... if I use
  `this.model.get('thesubpart')`, I think I will be passing a value, not
  a reference.
- **Bind the child event in the parent view** : is this the way to go?  I'm
  not sure how I would go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit confusing, but I think you want a child model to react to something happening in a parent model, though I'm not sure if the parent is a collection or a single model itself.

The preferred way to do this is through events (i.e. `parent.on('change', child.handleParentChange)`, where handleParentChange is a function defined on the child model. Since you seem to be interested in only a specific attribute change, you could bind to the more specific "change:thesubpart" event.

There are different ways to do this, such as an event aggregator, but the general idea is the same. [Be careful of zombies](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/), though. If the parent outlives the child, it will keep the child in memory because of the binding (an advantage of the event aggregator, if implemented correctly).

Comment: Parent model is a single model containing a collection, I want to child's model to be this collection only, not the whole parent model.